# Is there any interactive console I can use to test javascript behavior in IE (9.0)

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I want to check some javascript statements behavior quickly. Is there any build-in tool could make this? I just want to verify it in the javascript engine of IE. So other browser is not help here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

F12 opens a developer window in IE (>8 and up). At the top of the window you can change the IE version/mode. The javascript can be tested using the 'script' tab, within which you also find a 'start debugging' button and a command line (bottom right) which can be enlarged. You can use the latter to test individual js-statements.

Answer (score 1):

Sauce Labs has quick cross-browser testing. You could use that.

It might also be worth your time to invest in VMWare / Parallels, Windows, and IE9. You'll probably have to do testing in the future too.

Answer (score 1):

Check this : [Scripting Debugging in Internet Explorer](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2004/10/26/247912.aspx)